# Specification Attributes Globally in nopCommerce 2.2

Tags: nopcommerce

I am newbie to nopCommerce 2.2,which uses MVC framework. I am having the specification attribute for the category page which will filter only the products that comes under a particular category. I wanted to have the specification attributes globally in the search.cshtml file similar to the price range I get there. Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its late to answer this question, but for anyone who is searching for the same solution. I have written anrticles on it which you can find it on my blog;

[http://dotnetdreamer.com/post/2014/04/13/custom-attribute-searching-in-nopcommerce-3-3](http://dotnetdreamer.com/post/2014/04/13/custom-attribute-searching-in-nopcommerce-3-3.aspx)

Comment: http://www.dotnetdreamer.com/custom-attribute-searching-in-nopcommerce-33-part-2-the-dynamic-way